# No matching fbConfigs or visuals found, while openning Qt Creator over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, display-driver, opengl, qt

I have Qt 5.12.7 64 installed on Debian 9.12, these are running on vmware on Windows host.

Then I use macOS and ssh into debian. And I tried to open Qt Creator and got:

```
$ ~/Qt5.12.7/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

Locally, I mean not from ssh, I can open Qt Creator normally.

I found similar error on https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update?noredirect=1&lq=1, though there solution goes on to install nvidia driver. I'm guessing I might have another problem, since it works locally so driver installation might be right?

So what else should I check?